# EF Core: Efficient way to add multiple unrelated rows into database without a transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 3.1 on top of SQL Azure. I don't actually know if this is a SQL question or an EF Core question. Imagine that there's a required relationship to a "Company" entity via a "CompanyId".

```cs
_dbContext.Users.Add(new User()
{
    CompanyId=1,
});
_dbContext.Users.Add(new User()
{
    CompanyId=1,
});
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Works fine.

```cs
_dbContext.Users.Add(new User()
{
    CompanyId=1,
});
_dbContext.Users.Add(new User()
{

});
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

gives:

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
> constraint "FK_Users_Company_CompanyId"... The statement has been
> terminated.

This is expected for the second item. Based on what I'm seeing it seems that EF (Or SQL Server) is wrapping all pending db context changes inside of a single transaction and rolling back all of the changes if any of the inserts fails.

But what if I'm batching multiple inserts together solely to be more efficient, and not because they are related to one another? I'm curious if I could have it keep the correct entry written to the database and only reject the bad one.

Or, am I misguided that it's more efficient to wrap multiple inserts into a single SaveChanges() call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Only when saveChanges() is called all the inserts, deletes and updates you have done are comitted to the database, so it works indeed as a transaction. If you want to keep the 'correct entry' you should call saveChanges() after it, like this:

```cs
_dbContext.Users.Add(new User()
{
    CompanyId=1,
});
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
_dbContext.Users.Add(new User()
{

});
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Thats the only way to do it with EF Core. Remember you also have addRange() if you want to add a group of items.

Please refer to the following link for more information - [Transaction in Entity Framework](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/transaction-in-entity-framework.aspx)